# issue with While Loops C#

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have a rock paper scissors program that asks for your input, makes a random cpu input, compares them and then declares the winner of that round. I tried to make a while loop that when a round is over, it plays again until someone is at 3 points. After one round is over the program seems to break.
I have quoted the while loop.
Thank you!

```cs
string playerInput;
string cpuInput;
int randomInt;
bool playAgain = true;
int scorePlayer = 0;
int scoreCPU = 0;


while (scorePlayer > 3 && scoreCPU > 3);
{
    Console.WriteLine("Rock Paper or Scissors?");
    playerInput = Console.ReadLine();
    playerInput.ToLower();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    randomInt = rnd.Next(1, 4);
    switch (randomInt)
    {
        case 1:
            cpuInput = "rock";
            Console.WriteLine("CPU chose rock");
            if (playerInput == "rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DRAW!");
            }
            else if (playerInput == "paper")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PLAYER WINS!");
                    scorePlayer++;
            }
            else if (playerInput == "scissors")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CPU WINS!");
                scoreCPU++;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            cpuInput = "paper";
            Console.WriteLine("CPU chose paper");
            if (playerInput == "rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PLAYER WINS");
                scorePlayer++;
            }
            else if (playerInput == "paper")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DRAW!");

            }
            else if (playerInput == "scissors")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CPU WINS!");
                scoreCPU++;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            cpuInput = "scissors";
            Console.WriteLine("CPU chose scissors");
                if (playerInput == "rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CPU WINS!");
                scoreCPU++;
            }
            else if (playerInput == "paper")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PLAYER WINS!");
                    scorePlayer++;
            }
            else if (playerInput == "scissors")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DRAW!");
            }
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("INVALID INPUT!");
            break;
                if (scorePlayer == 3)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("PLAYER WON!");
                    }
                else if (scoreCPU ==3);
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("CPU WON!");
                }      
        }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: **[How to use the awesome, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies here:

```cs
int scorePlayer = 0;
int scoreCPU = 0;


while (scorePlayer > 3 && scoreCPU > 3);
```

Neither `scorePlayer` nor `scoreCPU` is greater than 3, so the loop condition fails.  The semicolon on the end is an *empty statement*.  Everything that follows is in a code block, but it's not the contents of the `while` loop.

Remove the semicolon and change your condition to allow the loop condition to succeed initially.
For example:

```cs
while (scorePlayer < 3 && scoreCPU < 3)
```

Using a debugger to examine the contents of your variables will help you understand why your loop is not working, and you'll see it step on the semicolon once the condition is right.

Answer (score 0):

As per program description you mentioned, it should run until one of the player or CPU have 3 points, allow the While loop to run until it meets the condition to break.

Change your While loop condition to:

```
while(scorePlayer < 3 && scoreCPU < 3)
```